# Intellij Idea Tomcat and Spring MVC template

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have just started to play with Spring MVC. I installed Intellij Idea and Tomcat server and then created a new project from SpringMVC template. When I run it I got the error:

```
Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
```

I solved it by changing Java jdk from version 1.8 to 1.7. When I run it then, I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.hello_jsp
```

To fix it I had to remove:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

from my pom.xml file and now it's working. Can someone tell me why this template won't work without these changes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without more detail about the error you got, I can't answer why you needed to change the Java version.

As for the `servlet-api` dependency, that is because Tomcat has its own implementation of the `servlet-api` included. So there was a clash. What you will want to do is add the dependency back into your POM with a scope of `provided`. That way it is there for your IDE to use as well as at build time. (Unless of course you are getting the `servlet-api` from some where else such as the `javaee-api` dependency).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```